# Cannot test simple sqlalchemy model dataclass: "Mapper mapped class could not assemble any primary key columns for mapped table"

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a simple Python script (`models.py`) to create a Flask-SQLAlchemy app and a simple sqlalchemy dataclass ([reference here](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/models/#simple-example)) that looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "sqlite:///test.db"
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class User(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'user'

    user_id: db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_url: db.Column(db.String(2083), unique=True, nullable=False)
    username: db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
    avatar_url: db.Column(db.String(2083), unique=True, nullable=False)
```

I then wrote an extremely simple pytest script that looks like this, following the example on creating a Flask-SQLAlchemy app from [here](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/quickstart/#quickstart):

```
import pytest

from models import User
from models import db

def test_basic():

    db.create_all()

    u1 = User(1, "http://testuserurl", "charliebrown", "http://avatarurl")

    assert u1.user_id == 1
    assert u1.user_url == "http://testuserurl"
    assert u1.username == "charliebrown"
    assert u1.avatar_url == "http://avatarurl"
```

This test fails immediately on the line "from models import User" with the message:

> sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Mapper mapped class User->user could not
> assemble any primary key columns for mapped table 'user'

I don't understand this message (specially given that I do indeed specify the `primary_key` in `User`). Any help please?

Comment: In `foo: Bar` the Bar is an annotation. You want class attributes instead, so assignments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `=` instead of `:`

Like this:

```
class User(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'user'

    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_url = db.Column(db.String(2083), unique=True, nullable=False)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
    avatar_url = db.Column(db.String(2083), unique=True, nullable=False)
```

Comment: Upvoted as is, but it'd make this a better answer, if you'd mention the difference between the two, and why one works, but not the other.

Comment: Ah, I got confused with the dataclass decorator, that does use the foo: bar assignment! https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html

Comment: it raises `Invalid args for response field! Hint: check that {type_} is a valid pydantic field type` instead