# Use dataclass decorator in Flask-SQLAlchemy model class?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, python-dataclasses

I wrote a Flask-SQLAlchemy model class that looks like this (from this [reference](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/models/#simple-example)):

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class User(db.Model):
    
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_url = db.Column(db.String(2083), unique=True, nullable=False)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
    avatar_url = db.Column(db.String(2083), unique=True, nullable=False)
    
    def __init__(self, user_id, user_url, username, avatar_url):
    
        self.user_id = user_id
        self.user_url = user_url
        self.username = username
        self.avatar_url = avatar_url
```

However, I would like to use the `dataclass` decorator ([reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html)) to simplify the implementation of this, specifically to avoid overriding the `__init__` dunder method, and to make it easier to serialize this class into a Python `dict`.

However, changing the implementation of this class to:

```
@dataclass
class User(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'user'

    user_id: db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_url: db.Column(db.String(2083), unique=True, nullable=False)
    username: db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
    avatar_url: db.Column(db.String(2083), unique=True, nullable=False)
```

Does not work, yielding an error similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67710241/cannot-test-simple-sqlalchemy-model-dataclass-mapper-mapped-class-could-not-as) ("Mapper mapped class could not assemble any primary key columns for mapped table").

Any help on how to simplify classes with baseclass `db.Model` by using the `dataclass` decorator (or alternative solution)?

Comment: You are treating the actual instances of `db.Column` as types, rather than values that the `db.Model` metaclass will use to define the database interface.

Comment: the reference that you linked doesn't have a `__init__` function, why did you write one?

Comment: I was getting an error without the `__init__` function when trying something like `User(user_id=1, user_url="http://testuserurl", username="charliebrown", avatar_url="http://avatarurl")`. Can´t seem to replicate that error anymore through.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know this is over a year old but answering for others struggling with this.

I feel your pain as I was going around in circles with Flask-Marshallow for ages trying to serialise my Flask-SqlAlchemy query.

The answer is that you have to put datatypes at the top of you Model class.  So using the OP's example you need to change this:

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    user_id: db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_url: db.Column(db.String(2083), unique=True, nullable=False)
    username: db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
    avatar_url: db.Column(db.String(2083), unique=True, nullable=False)
```

to this:

```
@dataclass
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    user_id: int
    user_url: str
    username: str
    avatar_url: str

    user_id: db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_url: db.Column(db.String(2083), unique=True, nullable=False)
    username: db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
    avatar_url: db.Column(db.String(2083), unique=True, nullable=False)
```

Note that you only need to declare the data type for the fields you need to serialise.